# What is the graphql type for numbers in node?

Tags: graphql, numbers

Sorry, I searched the docs to no avail.

This works:

```
import { GraphQLString } from "graphql";
```

These doesn't:

```
import { GraphQLNumber } from "graphql";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Javascript does not differentiate between floats, doubles, and integers (having only a single type "number"), graphql and databases do.

You have to use these:

```
import {  GraphQLInt, GraphQLFloat } from "graphql";
```